# Nifi ExecuteGroovyScript trigger onStart with TestRunner

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, apache-nifi

I am currently struggling with writing tests for my ExecuteGroovyScript process. I am able to do a lot of things with the Nifi Testrunner and MockingFlowFiles but I dont find a way to trigger the onStart callback for the GroovyScript.

I need the onStart as [described here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html) to initially (and only once) load a config for the processor and provide it to the script. It works as described in Nifi itself, but the onStart is not called while executing the tests with the TestRunner.

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() throws IOException {
    runner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(ExecuteScript.class);
    runner.setProperty("Script Engine", "Groovy");
    runner.setProperty("converterconfig", IOUtils.toString(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    runner.setProperty(ScriptingComponentUtils.SCRIPT_BODY,
        IOUtils.toString(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("converter.groovy")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    runner.assertValid();
}

@Test
public void processSuccessfulEvent() throws IOException {
    String inputString = IOUtils.toString(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("input.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    runner.enqueue(inputString);
    runner.run();

    runner.assertTransferCount(ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS, 1);
}
```

---

```
//Groovyscript
static onStart(ProcessContext context){
    //do stuff with the config, but this is never called/triggered in the testrunner
    def config = context.getProperty("converterconfig")
    ...
 }
```

Does anyone have an advise how to get the tests to trigger the onStart? Nifi version is 1.12 and Groovy 2.4.16

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are testing executescript, but onStart implemented only in executegroovyscript processor